# Android systems files ,<resource> and <assets> in particular

Tags: android, file, system, file-manipulation

I am trying to write a code that lets me programmatically switch a file from one of my resources folders to my assets folder.  I have tried the usual `file.renameTo` method that has worked so very well for me in the past....but with android it seems to do nothing...

Comment: Are you trying to move a file into or out of the /res folder? That won't work in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assets and res folders are part of the structure of the .apk file. This isn't something that can be changed by the application on the phone. You can create a folder structure in the phone's file system, but that will need to be accessed from your app by the file access api, not as assets or resource identifiers.